# Cloth Simulation not touching the surface

Tags: physics

[image]

I'm having a problem with cloth simulation.

The surfaces (the bowl and table top) is with Collision for Physics.

And the cloth is with Cloth Simulation.

The problem is that the cloth is not touching any of the surfaces and I've already set the collision distance to 0.1cm (which is the minimal allowed).

Why is this "void" around my bowl and surface?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunatelly Blender physics is pretty bed with small distances. So the best what you can do is upscale 10-100 times everything before start the simulation. After you can downscale it or just render.

Comment: Now that you've told me, it makes sense. And I did that, it worked! Thank's a lot. The only thing that keeps me thinking is that in the tutorial that I'm following, it works just fine even with the same dimensions I'm using.

That's really strange. But thank's a lot, man!